# Компоновка всех файлов программы в единый файл.

Tags: windows, файлы, exe, dll

Здравствуйте!
Есть способ засунуть все компоненты приложения в один единый исполняемый файл. Например, у меня есть 2 DLL библиотеки, 3 исполняемых файла, 1 текстовый и несколько(5-6) картинок. Для правильной работы этого приложения необходимы все файлы. При чем всё это месиво надо копировать еще в два места. Делать это с таким массивом файлов неудобно, удобнее засунуть все это дело куда-нибудь в экзешник и уже его копировать в нужные места. Так вот, как это можно сделать? Спасибо

---

Мне нужен не инсталятор, а инструмент, объединяющий все файлы в один и при запуске которого все будет работать, а не инсталлироваться.

Comment: А требуется выполнение их из пака? Или копирование из пака, затем запуск?

Comment: Можно из пака. Вообще все равно как, главное, чтобы копировался один файл в нужное место и корректно работало приложение вцелом. После копирования пака можно файлики оттуда вытащить.

Comment: Это называется инсталлятор :(

Comment: нет, @karmadro4, мне нужен НЕ инсталятор! Гыы

Comment: А у Вас **`.NET`**-приложение или нативное для Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите в сторону виртуализации приложений. Средств для этого существует немало:

- [VMware ThinApp](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ThinApp)
- [P-Apps](http://portable-app.com/)
- [Xenocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoon_(software)) и т.д.

Кстати, ThinApp нынче весьма популярен среди создателей разного рода "портабельных" программ.